# Check if a primary key already exists

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql, primary-key, any

I'm trying to check if a `primary key` exists before trying to add another record using the code below. I know the table has a pk of 15, so the `if` statement should be true, but the code doesn't work. The `if` statement is false and I get an error on `submitchanges()` saying I can't add a duplicate key. Is this the best method to check if a pk exists and if so what is wrong with the code?

```
'check if an existing PK exists
        Dim lkup = From z In DATA.MONTE_CARLOs
                   Where z.ID = 15
                   Select z

        If lkup.Any() = False Then
            DATA.BOOKs.InsertOnSubmit(newBOOK)
        End If

        DATA.SubmitChanges()
```

Comment: Is the PK 15 already stored in DB or is it changed in code only? Do you use EF? Btw...it´s much easier when you set the ID field to auto_increment and let the database do the PK check.

Comment: tks Alex...yes the PK of 15 is already in a datatable (I can see it when I look at the table data). What's EF? the ID pk is used to link to another table so I can't set it to auto-increment.

Comment: Seems like your checking and inserting executes in different tables `MONTE_CARLOs` and `BOOKs`. Is this possible that `BOOKs` table contains `ID = 15`, but `MONTE_CARLOs` not?

Comment: EF = [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx). And for sure you can use a auto_increment while using foreign keys.

Comment: Fabio you were right! thanks I couldn't see the wood for the trees.

Comment: Alex I'm using visual studio. I'm not sure how to use auto_increment while using foreign keys, tks I'll take a look.

Comment: I assume you are using SQL Server so the correct term is `identity`. Example: `CREATE TABLE A
(ID integer IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY)

CREATE TABLE B
(ID integer PRIMARY KEY,
A_ID integer,
CONSTRAINT FK_AB FOREIGN KEY (A_ID) 
    REFERENCES A (ID))`
Column ID in Table A will now be auto increment. Whe inserting a record to table B it is checked that A_ID exists in Table A.

Comment: thanks I'll take a look. But I'm also using linq to sql so inheritance may be an easier way to go

Comment: So how do you create your database model?